# Run randomForest with mtry

Tags: r, random-forest

I got this kind of error in studying `randomforest`.

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
rf_model_housing <-train(SalePrice ~., # Standard formula notation
data=train_housing[,-1],
method="rf",
nodesize= 10,
mtry= 5,            
ntree = 500,
trControl=trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=2,repeats=1),
tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = c(123)))
```

> Error: Stopping
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: mtry=123 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) : 
>     formal argument "mtry" matched by multiple actual arguments
>    2: model fit failed for Fold2.Rep1: mtry=123 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) : 
>     formal argument "mtry" matched by multiple actual arguments
>    3: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Comment: try deleting `mtry = 5`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of randomForest for caret [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#Random_Forest), you are using too many tunig parameters and  they need to be put in a data.frame grid (see [here for one example](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process)).
Moreover you defined 2 times `mtry`, the number of predictors used for splitting. I suggest trying something like :

```r
rf_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=5)

rf_grid <-  expand.grid(mtry = c(floor(sqrt(ncol(x)) / 10),
                        floor(sqrt(ncol(x)) / 5),
                        floor(sqrt(ncol(x)))
)

set.seed(123)
rf_fit <- train(SalePrice ~., 
                 data = train_housing[,-1], 
                 method = "rf", 
                 trControl = rf_control,
                 tuneGrid = rf_grid)
rf_fit
```